# On user registration, if welcome mail sent, add post with new user as author

Tags: user-registration, wp-mail

I am trying to create a new post (later will convert it into custom post type), whenever a new user register on the website and if the welcome email was sent succesfully. The problem is that I want to add the new user as the author of the new post. Later all notification emails will be accesible from a special page.

I'm trying to use the `wp_mail` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail_filter' );
function my_wp_mail_filter( $args ) {

    $new_wp_mail = array(
        'to'          => $args['to'],
        'subject'     => $args['subject'],
        'message'     => $args['message'],
        'headers'     => $args['headers'],
        'attachments' => $args['attachments'],
    );

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $args['subject'] . ' - ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_content'  => $new_wp_mail,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author'   => $user_id,
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_category' => array(0)
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );

    return $new_wp_mail;
}
```

I don't know how to get the user Id.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `wp_mail` filter use action `user_register`:

```
function fpw_new_user_post( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->base_prefix . 'capabilities', array( 'author' => TRUE ) );
    $new_post = array (
        'post_title'    => 'User ' . get_user_by( 'id', $user_id )->user_login . '  registered @ ' .  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
        'post_content'  => 'This is my first post.',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => $user_id,
        'post_category' => array( 0 )
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
    if ( 0 == $post_id ) {
        // do some error action
    }
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'fpw_new_user_post', 10, 1 );
```

Based on an assumption that you want this user to publish other posts later, I've changed his role to `author`. Of course you can set a new post to fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the meantime I've figured out, just forgot to mention here. But your answer is much appreciated and I like a lot the aproach, a little bit different from mine. Thanks a lot! :)